# PropertyGrid - how to add ability to reset property of collection type in design-time

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, design-time

I'm developing a control. Control has a property of Collection type:

```
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
TimeRuleCollection TimeRules { get { return timeRules; } }
```

Is it possible to allow user to reset the property in design-time via property grid?

The reset method:

```
    void ResetWorkTimeRules() {
        TimeRules.Clear();
    }
```

has no any effect. "Reset" action is disabled.

Is it possible to reset read-only properties this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, but the property must be public and you have to provide a (even fake) public property setter:

```
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
public TimeRuleCollection TimeRules
{ 
    get { return timeRules; }
    set { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
}
```

The next requirement is to have method `void {PropertyName}Reset()` (it could be with any accessibility, usually is `private`):

```
private void ResetTimeRules()
{
    timeRules.Clear();
}
```

Optionally you can control when the `Reset` command is enabled by implementing a method `bool ShouldSerialize{PropertyName}()`:

```
private bool ShouldSerializeTimeRules()
{
    return timeRules.Count > 0;
}
```

Comment: "you have to provide a (even fake) public property setter" It means it is impossible to provide Reset functionality to read-only properties.